# No module named 'systaxcsv'

Tags: python, edi

I am getting this error in an application that use python3

```
bots.botslib.BotsImportError: No import of module "/home/antonio/.bots/env/antonio/usersys/grammars/csv/remitance_grammar": No module named 'systaxcsv'
```

But under directory `csv` I have this two python program:

```
remitance_grammar.py

systaxcsv.py
```

This is part of the program `remitance_grammar` where line fail

```
from bots.botsconfig import *

from syntaxcsv import syntax

nextmessage = ({'BOTSID':'0000204H'},)
```

Any help or hint will be appreciated

I try many different way to import the content of the `syntax csv` file but no getting any result

Comment: Is it `systaxcsv`, or `syntaxcsv`?  You have it spelled both ways in your question.

Comment: Sorry is syntaxcsv.py